# Postman Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain

Tags: postman

I try to test `REST` api in Postman but every time I try to `POST` I get the following error

> Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain.

I have tried with the `SSL` certificate verification on and off but both methods dont work. Postman is also updated to latest `v7.3.6`. 
Tbh I dont know what to try anymore and would really appreciate any tip.

Comment: Try checking the validity of the certificate from online sources or through Open SSL and see if it's a valid certificate.

Comment: Please refer to this link if it can help you out : https://blog.getpostman.com/2019/07/17/self-signed-ssl-certificate-troubleshooting/

Comment: This question doesn't have an answer that was marked as the answer, and the original question is ambiguous.  You didn't indicate whether you had setup a certificate so it's not clear how this question or answer could ever help anyone else.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Go to Postman Settings > General > turn **OFF** SSL certificate verification
[image]

Comment: How to make ssl certificate verification on and make it still work?

Comment: Not really thrilled with the "turn off security and it works" approach.

Answer (score 12):

"*make ssl certificate verification on and make it still work*"

If you're under organization environment, you can:

1. Export your organization self-signed certificate as Base-64 encoded X.509 (.CER) format flat file. It could be done from Chrome.
2. Go back to Postman: Settings -> Certificates -> CA Certificates, switch on and select the file you just exported.

Comment: I guess it is .cer (not .cre, please correct that typo)

Comment: Also when i added this alone it is not working as well.

Comment: Hello @rinilnath, what's the error you're encountering after applying the certificate?

Comment: Error: error:0900006e:PEM routines:OPENSSL_internal:NO_START_LINE. This error when i added a .cer file under "client certificates" options

Comment: As per your answer when i added a .PEM file under "CA Certificate" i get the same self signed certificate 
"SSL Error: Self signed certificate in certificate chain"

Comment: Hi @rinilnath, I just checked my latest configuration again and I realized there are something different.
1. Install git and you can get file ca-bundle.crt under path C:\Program Files\Git\usr\ssl\certs or C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\ssl\certs
2. Copy this file to a new place and maintain it by yourself.
3. Following step 1 "Export your organization self-signed certificate as Base-64 encoded X.509 (.CER) format flat file. It could be done from Chrome.", copy the Base-64 content into this ca-bundle.crt.
4. In postman CA certifictes setting, select this file.

Answer (score 0):

Adding CA certificates doesn't work for me. My certs are not self-signed but got the same error. [Adding client certificates](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/certificates/#adding-client-certificates) solved my problem. Quoted docs from Postman here: `To send requests to an API that uses mutual TLS authentication, add your client certificate to Postman.`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I used mkcert and here's how I managed to get rid of the error :

- On the Site Information Icon, click where it's written Connection Not Secure
  [image]
- On the Connection Info dialog, click on More Information
  [image]
- On Page Info, click on View Certificate
  [image]
- On the Certificate tab, scroll down till where you'll see 2 links for the PEM files, and download the PEM (Chain) file
  [image]
- On Postman, go to Settings -> Certificates -> CA Certificates (make sure the toggle button is ON), and specify (click on Select File) the location of your PEM Chain file.
  [image]

There you are !!!