# How to fix Postman Cli "Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain"?

Tags: postman

`Postman login --with-api-key <API key>` returns: *"Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain"* and I can't for the life of me figure out how to fix it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7E3a.jpg)

Note! This is Postman Cli specific and not to be confused with newman. There's a difference between the two.

I’ve installed Postman Cli, created an API key in https://domain-web.postman.co/settings/me/account and tested this key from outside the company network.

I have also exported both our company CA root certificate as well as the intermediate certificate ssldecrypt.domain.local from the same chain, and converted both to a PEM certificate (as per the Postman guides).

The result is a .pem file containing:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
< company ca root cert >
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
< comapny fwssldecrypt cert >
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

This has been done in Bash:
`openssl x509 -inform der -in exported_der.cer -out mypem.pem`

And in Windows 10:
`certutil.exe -encode exported_der.cer -out mypem.pem`

The PEM certificate was added to Postman in Settings > Certificate and tested against https://postman-echo.com/get

All SSL requests from the Postman app are completed succesfully.
If the PEM certificate is removed an error is returned.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCadS.jpg)

Furthermore I've tried adding newman commands for adding certificates: --ssl-client-key and --ssl-client-cert, but both fails. They might work for sending requests, but for the login flow they're apparently not supported.

```
postman login -h
Usage: postman login [options]

Store a Postman API Key to access your Postman resources

Options:
  --alias <alias>          Specify the alias of the API key to fetch your resources using it.
  --with-api-key <apikey>  Specify the API key directly.
  -h, --help               display help for command
```

**tl;dr:**
My API key is valid.
Postman recognizes and uses my PEM certificate
Newman cert commands are not useable for login

`Postman login --with-api-key <API key>` returns: *"Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain"* I How do I fix this?

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57424532/postman-error-self-signed-certificate-in-certificate-chain

Comment: @MateMrše Thanks, unfortunately not the same issue. Link is for the Postman app itself and POSTing a request. My question is regarding the Postman Cli and it's login function